# How is it possible for someone to "Protect against Future Unknown Attacks"

Tags: cryptanalysis

In section 4.4 (page 6) of [Camellia: A 128-Bit Block Cipher Suitable for Multiple Platforms - Design and Analysis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1e2c/f01396552ffe256d3e1ea568284124269a1f.pdf), it says

> $FL$ and $FL^{−1}$ functions are inserted between every 6 rounds
>   of a Feistel network to provide non-regularity across rounds. One of
>   the goals for such a design is to thwart future unknown attacks.

How we can thwart against attack which we dont know, or which is yet to be discovered or established?

Comment: One should explain the reason for negative vote so that such questions can be avoided in future.

Comment: I've up voted because $FL$ and $FL^{-1}$ are indeed questionable in this context.

Comment: This resonates with Donald Rumsfeld's initially lampooned yet later categorised as deeply insightful "Known unknowns" speech.

Answer (score 1):

> How we can thwart against attack which we dont know, or which is yet to be discovered or established?

I'll just answer in the generic sense: by adding complexity. The complexity / irregular structure of the function(s) may not be directly needed for the (incomplete) security proof of the overall cipher but it may still need to be overcome by attacks on it.

For instance, a function could be used to hide a regular algorithmic structure, so that the cipher cannot easily be written down as a set of mathematical equations. New advances may make it easier to solve the equations for a (partially) unknown key. So those kind of attacks may be avoided by adding complexity.

Of course, with the attacks being unknown, it's impossible to be sure such attacks would be thwarted. So it's a goal which is only reached if one or more attacks are nulled or at least made computationally hard.

Comment: Any Camellia specific explanation should  take preference over this answer.